# Finding a better way to do a top 1 per group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am attempting to find the most recent `value` per `id` that is older than `1/1/2013`

```
create table #foo
(
    id int,
    value money,
    entry_date datetime
)

insert into #foo values (1, 1.00, '1/1/2012')
insert into #foo values (1, 2.00, '2/1/2012')
insert into #foo values (1, 7.00, '1/1/2013')
insert into #foo values (2, 1.00, '1/1/2013')
insert into #foo values (2, 1.00, '2/1/2013')
insert into #foo values (3, 5.00, '3/1/2012')
```

The following gives me the solution but I know I am doing this the wrong way.

```
select id, value
from
(
    select id, value, row_number() over (partition by id order by entry_date desc) as ind
    from #foo
    where entry_date < '1/1/2013'
) a where ind = 1

--Results:
--id          value
------------- ---------------------
--1           2.00
--3           5.00
```

Id 2 is not returned due to not having any records older than 1/1/2013.

What is the correct way to accomplish what I am attempting to do?

Comment: Why is that the wrong way?

Comment: I would think that the nested query would be horribly inefficient with a real world dataset due to the fact that I select the entire table out, then I do another select on the result where the result of `row_number` was 1.

Comment: You've mistyped `1/1/2003` in the first line, can't edit as it's less than 6 chars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also use a subquery to get the result:

```
select f1.id, f1.value
from #foo f1
inner join
(
  select id, max(entry_date) entry_date
  from #foo
  where entry_date < '1/1/2013'
  group by id
) f2
  on f1.id = f2.id
  and f1.entry_date = f2.entry_date;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13266)

Comment: Not going to help if `entry_date` is non-unique (per `id`), though.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Yes, if they have more than one entry per date then this will return both.

Comment: All you need to add is a select top 1 order by date desc to get the right conditions in the sub query and it will work....

Comment: @IanP Why do you think that is needed?  The query as written will return the most recent value or values for each id.

Comment: Because the original op specified only one record...unless it was edited "the most recent" not "the most recent and any others on the same day"

Comment: @ScottChamberlain If you have multiple entries for the same day, what do you use as the identifier for the most recent value then?

Comment: Additional columns that I excluded from this simplified example. I guess I could add those columns to your method.

Answer (score 2):

This is along the same lines, but you can also use a `TOP 1 WITH TIES` in combination with the `ROW_NUMBER()` to eliminate the need for a subquery:

```
select top 1 with ties id, value
from #foo
where entry_date < '1/1/2013'
order by row_number() over (partition by id order by entry_date desc)
```

It's a little cleaner, in my opinion. Unfortunately, it can also perform slightly slower. Still, it's always good to know different uses for SQL functions.

Comment: I made a typo, that order by inside the over should be entry_date. It has been corrected in the main question.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks, I didn't see that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: What is `ties` I have never seen that keyword used before. Also I am not getting the same values for results in my real data set when i try both your method and mine.

Comment: Normally `TOP N` will return exactly `N` records, even if multiple records match the criteria. `WITH TIES` indicates that your query should grab `N` records, along with any other records that also match the last record in the result set based on your `ORDER BY`. Since the `ORDER_BY` here will be based on `ROW_NUMBER`, it will basically match on `ROW_NUMBER() = 1`

Comment: interesting approach, but forced to make two costly sorting operation.btw, +1

Answer (score 1):

With `SQL-Server 2005` you have ranking functions and common-table-expressions(CTE).

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT id,value,entry_date,
          RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY entry_date DESC)
   FROM dbo.TableName
   WHERE entry_date < '1/1/2013'
)
SELECT id,value,entry_date FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

returns the most recent record per id, so `ORDER BY entry_date DESC` instead of `value`.

If you want all "max-recent" values in case there are multiple, replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `DENSE_RANK`.

Comment: Does the CTE perform any different than my solution or is it a different way of doing the same thing?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Does the exact same thing.  Check the execution plan.

Comment: I have used a different order by as mentioned in the answer. But maybe I have misunderstood the problem anyway.

Comment: That was a typo, the original question was updated to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Use option with [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188336%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) operator

```
SELECT t.id, t.value
FROM #foo t
WHERE t.entry_date < '1/1/2013'
 AND EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM #foo t2
            WHERE t.id = t2.id
              AND t2.entry_date < '1/1/2013'
            HAVING MAX(t2.entry_date) = t.entry_date
            )
```

Demo on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13271)

For improving performance use this index:

```
CREATE INDEX x ON #foo(id, entry_date) INCLUDE(value)
```